# Android button and edit text

Tags: android, button, webview, android-edittext, google-play

I hav only a little exp in android.. nw I am developing an app ..it has one edit text and one button and a web view...the user can enter any keyword in edit text when the user presses the button it has to search the android market and the result has to displa in webview..nw i knw hw to display a web page in the webview....`

```
package com.example.webviewsimple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

`

this is the code used to search the market

`

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=com.amazon.kindle"));
   startActivity(i);

`
```

Comment: What is your problem..?

Comment: I would like to combine all these things...like when an user type a keyword in edit text and press the search button....it has to search the android market and display the results....

Comment: you don't have access to google play's database. how can u perform a search and display it in your app. think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this way : **`this code is only work in android device`**

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="search on Google Play" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="searchData"
        android:text="search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_test);
    }

    public void searchData(View v) {
        EditText ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String search = "market://search?q=";
        search += ev.getText().toString();
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            String appPackageName = getPackageName();
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(search));
            marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            startActivity(marketIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

check this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks Dhaval..... this will check for apps ..is there any possibility check inside the apps... and display the results

Comment: thanks Dhaval for your patience...I mean that...suppose an app that providing videos of movies ...so when we search for a keyword like for example "Don" ..is it possible to get the result of that particular movie which is inside the app...

Comment: hi...but the app is not executing it says 'unfortunately stop\' ...i given Internet permission in the android manifest.xml ....

Comment: you are test this app in emulator or in device??

Comment: I tested this in emulator...I did same like u did ..but it is not working... then I add serchable.xml and changed andrid manifest...but then also..it didn't worked..

Comment: thanks Dhaval...its working...thanks 4 u r support...It was not working in the emulator bec...emul..dont have access to the play store...I have another doubt...is it possible to search for applications contents...like a movie that is playing inside an app..

Comment: no, as per my k'no you can't search inside app like (app details,photos.. etc).

Comment: k...thanks..Dhaval....one more doubt...is there any way to find the link of movie playing in an app...like the the url of the video that is playing...

Comment: this is just way: if video is playing in youtube. then you can get that in that user's watch histry if he/she is login in youtube. i have also another way but can you tell me from which app you have to do that???

Comment: thanks..Dhaval...I am trying to develop an app...that app has to find the url of the movie that is playig inside an app..for that i asked al this..suppose...for ex: a movie named Don ihae to find..my app has tos earch this movie in the play store and has to list all apps that providing link for this movie...and i have to find te url of the movie...this is m need.

Comment: read this: you can access only this : http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html